# Is the sizeof() value determined by compiler or linker?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker, sizeof

I'm trying to troubleshoot a c++ problem where two parts of my code are returning different results for the sizeof() operator.

Here's what I run

```
MyClass* foo = new MyClass();
int size = sizeof(*foo)
```

I place this code in two different sections of my project and I get two different results. One time it 2254, another is 2284. I can look at the memory layout and one area shows the internal members as byte-aligned, another area it's word aligned.

I look at the dissasmbly and see that the sizeof() values are actually part of the machine code. Would this be a bug in the compiler or the linker? Why would two parts of the same project view the same class differently?

EDIT:

Let me provide a more clear example that I just ran to show that this is NOT a ODR violation.

I just made a brand new class as such

```
class TestAlignClass
{
public:  
    TestAlignClass() { }
    ~TestAlignClass() { }

private:
    char charArray[3];
    int myInt;
};
```

If the class is aligned to 4, it should return sizeof() = 8 which is what I want. But there are certain classes in my code that return sizeof() = 7.

In fact when I step into the new() operator, sometimes it allocates 7 bytes and sometimes it allocate 8.

I am linking several projects together and I thought it had to do with project settings at first, but different parts of the same project will show the discrepancy.

Comment: `sizeof` returns a compile-time constant. As to why you get discrepancies, no one can tell without real code (IOW: please provide a *minimal* example that reproduces the problem -- even though I'm pretty sure that in the process of making a minimal example you'll find your problem by yourself).

Comment: sizeof(whatever) is determined by compiler. Why does this happen - no idea, ODR violation, maybe?

Comment: It's clear that `sizeof` is working correctly: you've got two definitions of `MyClass` somehow, one byte aligned and one not.

Comment: I ran into this when linking two projects, one with default alignment of 4, and one with default alignment of 1.  Are you linking two projects?  If not, look for alignment pragmas.

Comment: Like always, always assume the bug is in your code, not in your compiler.

Comment: Any way you could provide a minimal example that actually demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @JohnDibling Does the edit I made suffice?

Comment: @DanQ:  Unfortunately, not quite.  A `main()` function with two `sizeof`s returning different values would, however.  Can you write one?

Comment: @DanQ: Minimal example means, something we can reproduce ourselves at the very least using the same compiler/version as you. Clearly your last edit isn't enough. ;) Think "new, independent project" that shows your problem (even if it has to be several files).

Comment: Unfortunately it's being cross compiled for an embedded system with several other 3rd party libraries. I'll try to come up with a better example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sizeof` is evaluated at compile time.

As for why `sizeof` returns different values for the same construct in two different places, the classes must be defined differently somehow in the different translation units.

One place I would look first is the packing.  If there is a `#pragma pack (1)` type expression in one TU but not in another, that could account for the difference.  It could also indicate a violation of the One Definition Rule, but that's another story.

Another, perhaps more exotic thing to look for is the presence of `#ifdef` type macros which effect what is part of the class.

As @MooingDuck rightly observes in the comments, it is extremely likely that the bug is in your code.  Do not assume the compiler is defective.

Comment: Please look at my edit with the test class. There are no #ifdefs used. I'm looking to see if there are any stray #pragma packs that could be getting included.

Comment: @DanQ:  I saw it.  I'm thinking about it.  Since you said you see this happein in a single module, and you are certian it is not an ODR violation, is it possible for you to provide a complete but minimal example that actually demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @DanQ:  By the way, `sizeof` returning `7` strongly suggests to me that packing is happening somewhere.  Modern CPUs do not align on a 7-byte boundary. :) (Disclaimer:  I don't do embedded systems.  Buyer beware.)

Comment: @DanQ Embedded or not, cross-compiling or not, unless your compiler is really weird and non-standard this shouldn't be an issue. Please provide as much information as you can (compiler, version, host and target platforms, what not... but of course minimal code would be a good addition).

Comment: Alright, previously my main() was returning sizeof() = 7. I gutted all the includes and only left my test class and now it is returning 8. There must be a rogue #pragma in some include file. Thank you for jogging my brain a bit. Now I Just need to figure out which one...

Comment: @DanQ:  Well, you're halfway home.  See if you can get your compiler to do the work for you.  Or use `grep`.  Good luck.